# How do you "catch" a pod2usage exit in a Perl Script with Try::Tiny?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, try-catch

I'm currently trying to learn unit testing. To do this I'm writting a script at work, and I'm creating unit tests for the entire script. Thus far things have been going well, but I'm trying to test that incorrect data entered into the script form the command line triggers a help message.

My code looks something like:

```
sub getContext{
   my ($help) = @_;

GetOptions(
  help|h => \$help,
   ...

pod2usage if $help;
... 
}
```

My tests look something like:

```
my $help_exception = 0;
try{  
   getContext( {help => 0} );
}catch{
 $help_exception = 1; 
}

ok($help_exception, "Script died correctly when given help flag");
```

---

My output looks very similar to:

```
1..4

ok 1 - use scripts::scriptname;

ok 2

ok 3

# Looks like you planned 4 tests but ran 3.

# Looks like your test exited with 1 just after 3.
```

---

The test for the help flag is test 4, it looks like my script is exiting without triggering the Try::Tiny try catch block. Is there a way to fix this, or should I be writing my tests differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Pod::Usage`](https://metacpan.org/module/Pod%3a%3aUsage#ARGUMENTS)'s documentation for it's `-exitval` argument shows how to stop it from exiting all together. You could simply use that and adapt your code and/or tests accordingly.

Otherwise, `exit` is not an exception, and therefore not trappable like an exception. However, it is overridable through `CORE::GLOBAL::exit`. Using that is a reasonable approach as well, assuming your properly localise your modifications.

Alternatively, you can always just start a subprocess to run your entire script and capture what it does, basing your tests on that, entirely avoiding the problem of `Pod::Usage` calling `exit`.

On a related note, the way you're using `Try::Tiny` in your test is a bit odd. I believe using [`Test::Fatal`](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aFatal) (which is based on `Try::Tiny`) might make for clearer tests in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, how would you localize a CORE::GLOBAL::EXIT override?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `pod2usage` does `exit` and not throwing an exception.  I don't think it can be captured this way.

Why not calling whole script in test and checking return value/output matches your expectations?

Answer (score 1):

As bvr answered: a program/script is not really unit testable as it's not made of reusable parts/units. You should test it holistically. Execute it with command line arguments and check its output and errors. E.g., using [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Capture%3a%3aTiny)–

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Capture::Tiny qw( capture );
use Test::More;

my $script = "/bin/ls";

plan skip_all => "Have no `$script` to check"
    unless -x $script;

my ( $out, $err ) = capture {
    system($script, "-1", "/");
};

like( $out, qr{^bin$}m, "$script finds bin" );
ok( ! $err, "...without error" );

done_testing(2);
```

Output from `prove`–

```
/home/apv/ab ..
ok 1 - /bin/ls finds bin
ok 2 - ...without error
1..2
ok
All tests successful.
```

Comment: I was using the modulino approach to test the script. This allows me to use mocks in my testing, which is necessary for the kind of script I'm writing (database access, configuration file access etc).                                                          http://www252.pair.com/comdog/mastering_perl/Chapters/18.modulinos.html